# Tweepy CustomStreamListener Class

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have the following code where I have made some amendments to the class 'CustomStreamListener':

```
import sys
import tweepy

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = "" 


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        for hashtag in status.entities['hashtags']:
            if hashtag == 'turndownforwhat':
                print(hashtag['text'])
                print status.text

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(locations=[-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8])
```

The bit I have added is everything within the class from the 'for' statement onwards. What I am trying to do is filter by the text values of the hashtags within text messages and then use some of the standard tweepy filters further down to filter by geolocation.

This has been built in Python 2.7. With my amendments the code does not error however it just hangs with no tweets coming through. Have I put a logical error in somewhere that I have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code has an error in the "if hashtag" condition.

It should be:

```
if hashtag['text'] == 'turndownforwhat'
```

You may need to wait a while to find a tweet that shows up, but if you use a bigger bounding box and a trending hashtag you will see results with this modification.